# Images for Retina display

Tags: iphone, xcode, retina-display

If i want my application to be compatible with the Retina display, am i obliged to recreate all my images by doubling their sizes? even the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not obligated, it just will look very pixelated if you don't.

As for the icon, I believe you are obligated to provide multiple sizes when submitting to the AppStore.

Answer (score 2):

if you will not use high resolution images your images will look pixelated/blurr.So better to use high res images as well.Some Key points are:

- Displaying graphics depending on the device model can be done by duplicating image files and adding an ‘@2x’ suffix. So, when the normal image file is named ‘button.png’, the hi-res version should be ‘button@2x.png’.
- You don’t need any additional code for this. In Interface Builder or your code, assign the normal version (without the suffix) to an object. ***The same goes for the application icon. The resolution of the 2x icon should be 114 by 114 pixels. You will need to add a separate ‘Icon’ property in the Info.plist file for this icon.***
- If for some reason you do want to perform a check in your code, you can do so by checking the scale factor of the display. Older models will return a scale factor of 1.0, while the iPhone 4 will return 2.0. You can check this with:

**float factor = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;**

Depending on the type of application you’re developing further optimizations can be made to utilize the new retina display the best you can.

[A very good information here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/17/designing-for-iphone-4-retina-display-techniques-and-workflow/)

hope it help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll want to take a look at [iRetiner](http://www.iynnis.com/4093-iretiner-adapting-the-icons-of-your-applications-to-retinal-display-cydia/).

You could also check this previous stackoverflow thread : [how to set image for ipad application that support retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920353/how-to-set-image-for-ipad-application-that-support-retina-display)

Answer (score 1):

A summary of the icons and what is required can be found in the [human interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).  I highly recommend providing high resolution artwork for the retina display even though it is not required.  Your default now should be to design artwork at the higher resolution, then scale down for older devices.  I doubt Apple would choose to highlight an application as new and noteworthy if it looks pixelated on the latest devices.